# Elixir passing reference of a module as function argument

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am very new to elixir/phoenix. I have a function like this

```
defp get_list(old_result, filter) do
  MY.Model.search_name(filter)
  |> Enum.concat(old_result)
end
```

Now, to make it more re-usable, I want to pass the reference of the `Model` to the function so it be something like:

```
defp get_list(old_result, filter, AnotherModel) do
  MY.AnotherModel.search_name(filter)
  |> Enum.concat(old_result)
end
```

But of course the above function does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the full module name as is as an ordinary param, like so:

```
defmodule A do
  def get_list(old_result, filter, some_module) do
    filter
    |> some_module.search_name
    |> Enum.concat(old_result)
  end
end

A.get_list(old_result, filter, MY.AnotherModule)
```

Answer (score 5):

While the answer by Kevin Johnson is perfectly valid, there is an exact solution for passing *the model only*, without namespace. It might be achieved with [`Module.concat/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#concat/2) followed by [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3):

```rb
defmodule A do
  @namespace MY
  def get_list(old_result, filter, model) do
    @namespace
    |> Module.concat(model)
    |> Kernel.apply(:search_name, [filter])
    |> Enum.concat(old_result)
  end
end
A.get_list(old_result, filter, AnotherModule) # note not FQ-name
```